# Django select and delete posts

Tags: python, django, web

I am making a blog based on Django on guides. I have a list of posts that you can change and delete. How to make it possible to select multiple posts and delete? I don't even know which side to approach the problem. All i need is are ways to complete this problem. I want to complete it by myself, but i need some advices about the ways how to do it

[image: Post edit]
[image: Post list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots of way to do that and it's usually a combination of frontend and backend, but in Django side you can filter rows (with lets say ids) and bulk delete them like this:

```
Post.objects.filter(id__in=(1, 2, 3, ...)).delete()
```

in frontend you should figure out a way to pass ids you want as a list to your Django view/api.